# Google Docs Form Script to make changes to UI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc Form and I need to make some UI changes to it. For example I want to increase the width of the form or for a grid question increase the width of the question column etc. Is this doable with Google App Script?

If possible, please suggest some other way of achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible directly in Google Apps Script. There are a few alternatives you have

1. Instead of using a Google Docs form, you can write the entire UI in Apps Script and control the width etc.
2. Open an issue in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to request for an enhancement.